# How to make string variables more than one word c++?

Tags: c++

When I am trying to store more than one word in a `string` variable, it only outputs one word when I tell the program to print it. This is an example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
string i;

int main() {
    cout << "Input more than one word." << endl;
    //in this case the user will input whats up//
    cin >> i;
    cout << i << endl;
    //the program outputs 'whats'//
}
```

Comment: You probably want [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: thank you everyone who replied i am very glad that online friends can help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `cin >> i`, use `getline(cin, i)`.

The difference is that, with `getline()` you get all the words in a line, whereas with `operator>>` you get only one word at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Replace that:

```
cin >> i;
```

for:

```
getline(cin, i);
```

and it will work :)